# 3 terms interaction in Cox PH model

Tags: regression, interaction, missing-data, cox-model

'''

1. coxph(formula = Surv(time, hyper) ~ age + drink + smoke + sodium * tchl * BMI, data = male)
2. coxph(formula = Surv(time, hyper) ~ age + drink + smoke + sodium * tchl * BMI, data = female)

- The 3-term variables are factors (=categorical)
- male patient:1506, control: 162
- female patient:1548, control: 363
- time: 7 periods

'''

```
 
The result of 3 terms interaction of 1 (male, n=1668)) : 

                         coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z     Pr(>|z|)
 sodium:tchl:BMI        NA         NA    0.000e+00     NA       NA 
The result of 3 terms interaction of 2 (female, n=1971) : 

<&nbsp>                 coef     exp(coef)   se(coef)     z    Pr(>|z|)
 sodium:tchl:BMI       4.545e-01  1.575e+00  1.582e+00  0.287    0.774
```

Why is the result of the male NA?

Comment: Please edit the table to provide a cross-table of the `sodium`, `tchl`, and `BMI` categorical predictors for males. My guess is that one combination category will have either no members or no events. Please also edit to define "tchl"; I infer that to be "total cholesterol" but I don't think that's a standard abbreviation. Finally, consider why you are modeling these continuous variables as categorical. I recall a lot of confusion when someone I know was diagnosed with "low sodium" when the value was 134, just below the arbitrary low cutoff of 135.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wondered why the different output came out for the same data types (males and females). And yes, tchl indicates total cholesterol. I abbreviated just for my convenience in my R code. The reason I divided the variables into categories is just for the group comparison, I understand your points, though. I don't think there are 0 but I'll check. thanks again.

Comment: Make sure to check whether there are _events_ in each combination of predictor values. Even if you have cases, without events the Cox model won't be able to calculate a finite coefficient estimate. Please show that breakdown by editing the question, otherwise there really isn't much more help to provide.

Comment: You may mean the following, which I found in the document. I guess 0 might be generated in the process of interaction calculation. Thank you.          **If the model contains strata by covariate interactions, then the y matrix may contain structural zeros, i.e., deaths (rows) that had no role in estimation of a given coefficient (column).**